# No features contain non-null values of in graphy

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi, reclassify, chart, multi-band

I want to graph the NDVI series by another classified image, but when I graph it there is a wrong No features contain non-null values of "system:index". Howvever I already set the system:index.

```js
var dem=ee.Image("USGS/SRTMGL1_003"); 
var roidem=dem.clip(roi); 
var product=ee.Terrain.products(roidem);
var aspect=product.select('aspect'); 
var asp=aspect.expression("(b('aspect')>90) ? 2"+                        ":(b('aspect')>270)?1"+ 
":1")
.rename("aspect")

var roi =   
    /* color: #d63000 */
    /* displayProperties: [
      {
        "type": "rectangle"
      }
    ] */
    ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-123.764453125, 41.955158501392994],
          [-123.764453125, 39.151105474903886],
          [-119.98515625, 39.151105474903886],
          [-119.98515625, 41.955158501392994]]], null, false);
var aspect=product.select('aspect');

var years2 = ee.List.sequence(2013, 2021);

var  landsat_NDVI_Y2 = ee.ImageCollection(years2.map(function(y){//if without imagecollection this will return list
  var start = ee.Date.fromYMD(y,1,1)
  var end = start.advance(12,'month')
  var ndvi = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_32DAY_NDVI')
              .filterDate(start,end)
              .select('NDVI')
              .max()
              .set('time',y)
  return ndvi.clip(roi)             
}))

print(landsat_NDVI_Y2,'landsat_NDVI_Y2')

var asp_class = asp.eq([1,2])

print(asp_class,'asp_class')

var ndvi_aspct = landsat_NDVI_Y2.map(function(image){
  return image.multiply(asp_class).set(image.toDictionary(image.propertyNames()));
})

var aspct1 = ndvi_aspct.select(0)
var aspct2 = ndvi_aspct.select(1)
print(aspct1,'aspect1')
print(aspct2,'aspect2')

var chart = ui.Chart.image.series({imageCollection:aspct1,
                       region:roi, 
                       reducer:ee.Reducer.mean(), 
                       scale:30, 
                       xProperty:'system:index'})
print(chart)
```

Comment: Add `asp` to make this example reproducible

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the error, my only issue was maxPixels error. You can increase the scale or reduce the data in a previous step, then plot. Check this answer: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/329315/gee-change-the-number-of-pixels-on-chart

Comment: I could reproduce the error by also using @aldo_tapia sugestion related to scale. Please, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You  are pointing out that already set the system:index but is not true. It can be easily corroborated by using your original Image Collection where is not included that property. As it was well pointed out by **aldo_tapia**, there is also exists a scale issue. Following code includes a 'system:time_start' property for generating the chart by using a scale of 300.

```
var roi =   
    /* color: #d63000 */
    /* displayProperties: [
      {
        "type": "rectangle"
      }
    ] */
    ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-123.764453125, 41.955158501392994],
          [-123.764453125, 39.151105474903886],
          [-119.98515625, 39.151105474903886],
          [-119.98515625, 41.955158501392994]]], null, false);

var years2 = ee.List.sequence(2013, 2021);

var  landsat_NDVI_Y2 = ee.ImageCollection(years2.map(function(y){//if without imagecollection this will return list
  var start = ee.Date.fromYMD(y,1,1)
  var end = start.advance(12,'month')
  var ndvi = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_32DAY_NDVI')
              .filterDate(start,end)
              .select('NDVI')
              .max()
              .set('time',y)
              .set('system:time_start', start);
  return ndvi.clip(roi)             
}))

print(landsat_NDVI_Y2,'landsat_NDVI_Y2')

var chart = ui.Chart.image.series({imageCollection:landsat_NDVI_Y2,
                       region:roi, 
                       reducer:ee.Reducer.mean(), 
                       scale:300, 
                       xProperty:'system:time_start'})
print(chart)
```

Result of running it in GEE code editor is as follows; where it can be observed a 'system:time_start'. With your original code was not generated error because you used xProperty:'system:index'; not 'system:time_start'. However, error is immediately produced by using 'system:time_start' property.

[image]

Now, you only have to adapt above code to use **aspct1** variable.